# How to implement action listener in ListView?

Tags: android, listview

Basically, I want to create a ListView with a bunch of items on it, and whenever the user click any item, it will open a new Activity according to which item he clicks. PLease, help me I would really appreciate it a lot.

Here is my my code:

```
package com.hipeople;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class char1 extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
private ListView lv1;
private EditText ed;
private String lv_arr[]={"Android","Cupcake","Donut","Eclairs","AndroidPeople","Froyo",};
private ArrayList<String>  arr_sort= new ArrayList<String>();
int textlength=0;
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
        {
            super.onCreate(icicle);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            lv1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
            ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
            lv1.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , lv_arr));





            ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }

            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                    int count) {

                textlength=ed.getText().length();
                arr_sort.clear();
                for(int i=0;i<lv_arr.length;i++)
                {
                    if(textlength<=lv_arr[i].length())
                    {
                        if(ed.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase((String) lv_arr[i].subSequence(0, textlength)))
                        {
                            arr_sort.add(lv_arr[i]);
                        }
                    }
                }


            }
            });


        }



    }
```

Comment: Please check out the [ListView tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html) to get off the ground with the basics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
      {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        {
            String str = ((TextView) arg1).getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),your_new_Intent.class);
            intent.putExtra("list_view_value", str);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your relpy, but it's giving some error "The type new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){} must implement the inherited abstract method AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.onItemClick(AdapterView<?>, View, int, long)". PLease help me

Comment: Can you just tell me how to switch activity using my code, because I don't want to change my layout. Please! I really appreactiate your help

Comment: Check out this nice and easy ListView tutorial, it will help you.

Comment: @user858975 let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2928/discussion-between-suri-sahani-and-user858975)

Comment: Are you getting the List in output?

Comment: Yes, I am getting the List in output. Basically, my only problem is I don't know how to implement an action listener on ListView using my code.

Comment: Well then just add a Listener to your lv1.setOnItemClickListenernew OnItemClickListener() 
      {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int arg2, long arg3) 
        {  // your new intent here }});

Comment: I made it work thanks, your code above is working properly I just forgot something thanks!